# UITextFields intermittently not allowing user interaction

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I know it's a very long shot and the problem description is vague at best, but I'm hoping someone might have encountered that as well.

I have a `UIViewController` subclass that is being presented modally. The view of the controller contains some `UIButton`s and some `UITextField`s. The view controller might be presented multiple times during a user session; it is created every time it's presented and gets destroyed when it's dismissed. Most of the time everything works as expected, however, sometimes the text fields don't respond to user touch, i.e. tapping them does not bring up the keyboard. The buttons on the view work fine, it's just the text fields that become disabled.

What could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the reason `UITextField`s inside a modally presented view controller were not responding was that one of the long-living view controllers in the app called `[self becomeFirstResponder]` on itself, but never called `[self resignFirstResponder]`. It had to be the first responder in order for it to receive remote controls events when the app was playing music.

Comment: Bottom line: have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, calling `[self resignFirstResponder]` on the said view controller before showing the modal view controller fixes it.